# Text XML to Sql Table... there and back again

Tags: sql-server, xml, data-conversion

I have a table:

```
with XMLData as (
    SELECT uid, commonname, cast(labeldetails as XML) labelxml
    FROM [MyLables]
)
SELECT 
     uid
    ,commonname
    ,labelxml
FROM
    XMLData [x]
```

I get (condensed for brevity):

```
B8A3DF5E    OrderType1  <NewDataSet><LabelData><Name>1d Vert</Name><Column>...
9D0F94C7    OrderType2  <NewDataSet><LabelData><Name>ItemNumber1D</Name><Co...
```

Inside Label Details is XML Data

```
<NewDataSet>
    <LabelData>
        <Name>mol</Name>
        <Column>mol</Column>
        <Type>MOLIMAGE</Type>
        <xpos>510</xpos>
        <ypos>110</ypos>
        <width>auto</width>
        <height>auto</height>
        <Font>Arial</Font>
        <Fontsize>10.0</Fontsize>
        <FontStyle>Normal</FontStyle>
        <Caption />
        <_x0032_DBarcode_Margin>1</_x0032_DBarcode_Margin>
        <_x0032_DBarcode_ModSize>5</_x0032_DBarcode_ModSize>
        <MOL_WIDTH>200</MOL_WIDTH>
        <MOL_HEIGHT>200</MOL_HEIGHT>
        <_x0020_MOL_MARGIN>15</_x0020_MOL_MARGIN>
        <MOL_BONDLINEWIDTH>2</MOL_BONDLINEWIDTH>
        <MOL_BONDSPACEING>5</MOL_BONDSPACEING>
        <MOL_FONTSIZE>15</MOL_FONTSIZE>
        <xpos_Inches>150</xpos_Inches>
        <ypos_Inches>600</ypos_Inches>
        <width_Inches>110</width_Inches>
        <height_Inches>510</height_Inches>
        <LogoImageName>110</LogoImageName>
        <ypos_int>110</ypos_int>
        <xpos_int>510</xpos_int>
    </LabelData>
    ....
    ....
</NewDataSet>
```

I want to cast the LabelDetails to XML and create a Temp Table that has the individual rows:

```
uid    commonname   id    name  column  type        xpos    ypox   ...
1234   OrderType1   1     col   col     TEXT        5       5      ...
1234   OrderType1   2     mol   mol     MOLIMAGE    1       1      ...
6789   OrderType2   1     col   col     TEXT        5       5      ...
```

I don't think all the XML Tables have all the same rows... Assume the don't

I've looked at other To/From XML questions and none of them seem to fit and I'm at a bit of a loss of where to go next...

Ultimately, I'm looking to convert to/from the XML data with the goal of using this as a "stop gap" between the old way our "system" stores this data and a new way of doing it.

Where can I start to create 2 stored procedures: FromXMLtoTable and FromTableToXML

Answer (score 2):

This will get you started. I had to do something similar. This may not be an exact answer, but has some code that you could use to get your XML data to a SQL table.

```
--Set tempXML for testing
CREATE TABLE #tempXML(id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, xmlData XML)
INSERT INTO #tempXML(xmlData)
VALUES('<NewDataSet>
    <LabelData>
        <Name>mol</Name>
        <Column>mol</Column>
        <Type>MOLIMAGE</Type>
        <xpos>510</xpos>
        <ypos>110</ypos>
        <width>auto</width>
        <height>auto</height>
        <Font>Arial</Font>
        <Fontsize>10.0</Fontsize>
        <FontStyle>Normal</FontStyle>
        <Caption />
        <_x0032_DBarcode_Margin>1</_x0032_DBarcode_Margin>
        <_x0032_DBarcode_ModSize>5</_x0032_DBarcode_ModSize>
        <MOL_WIDTH>200</MOL_WIDTH>
        <MOL_HEIGHT>200</MOL_HEIGHT>
        <_x0020_MOL_MARGIN>15</_x0020_MOL_MARGIN>
        <MOL_BONDLINEWIDTH>2</MOL_BONDLINEWIDTH>
        <MOL_BONDSPACEING>5</MOL_BONDSPACEING>
        <MOL_FONTSIZE>15</MOL_FONTSIZE>
        <xpos_Inches>150</xpos_Inches>
        <ypos_Inches>600</ypos_Inches>
        <width_Inches>110</width_Inches>
        <height_Inches>510</height_Inches>
        <LogoImageName>110</LogoImageName>
        <ypos_int>110</ypos_int>
        <xpos_int>510</xpos_int>
    </LabelData>
</NewDataSet>')

    SELECT r.value('Name[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS Field1
            , r.value('Column[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS Field2
            , r.value('Type[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS Field3
            --etc...
    FROM #tempXML
        CROSS APPLY xmlData.nodes('/NewDataSet/LabelData') AS x(r)
------------------------------------------------------------------------

    DECLARE @loopCount          INT
    DECLARE @recordID           INT
    DECLARE @columnName         NVARCHAR(128)
    DECLARE @dataType           NVARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @strSQL             NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @fieldValue         NVARCHAR(MAX)

    --This table will store your Columns from your new table of xml parsed data
    CREATE TABLE #TableFields
    (
        id int not null identity,
        COLUMN_NAME NVARCHAR(100),
        DATA_TYPE   NVARCHAR(10)
    )

    --Insert column names from xml parsed data to TableFields temp table
    INSERT INTO #TableFields (COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE)
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
    FROM Information_Schema.Columns 
    WHERE Table_Name = 'Insert Table Here'
            AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'ID'

    --Create your xml parsed table(or use a physical one)
    CREATE TABLE #temptable 
    (
        id INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
        field1 VARCHAR(100), 
        field2 VARCHAR(100),
        field3 VARCHAR(100)
        --etc...
    )

    --Insert the parsed xml from #tempXML test table to #tempTable
    INSERT INTO #temptable(fieldName, fieldValue, xmlID)
    SELECT r.value('Name[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS Field1
            , r.value('Column[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS Field2
            , r.value('Type[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS Field3
            --etc...
    FROM #tempXML
        CROSS APPLY xmlData.nodes('/NewDataSet/LabelData') AS x(r)

    --Set a loopCount for while loop
    SET @loopCount = 1

    --Use the while loop to check if we have any fields left to go through
        while ( exists(SELECT id FROM #TableFields WHERE id = @loopCount) )
            BEGIN

                --Get current record in temp table
                SELECT  @columnName     = t.COLUMN_NAME,
                        @dataType       = t.DATA_TYPE,
                        @fieldValue     = v.fieldValue,
                        @recordID       = v.xmlID
                FROM #TableFields t
                    JOIN #temptable v ON
                        t.id = v.id AND
                        t.COLUMN_NAME = v.fieldName
                WHERE t.id = @loopCount
                -----------------------------------------------------------         

                SET @strSQL = 'UPDATE [insert your table here] SET ' + @columnName + ' = ''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @fieldValue) + ''' FROM [insert your table here] WHERE ID = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @recordID)
                EXEC sp_executesql @strSQL, N'@columnName varchar(128)', @columnName = @columnName


                DELETE FROM #TableFields WHERE id = @loopCount

                SET @loopCount = @loopCount + 1
            END


    DROP TABLE #TableFields
    DROP TABLE #temptable
    DROP TABLE #tempXML
```

Comment: This might work, but is much to complicated... If ever possible avoid loops... There are many examples around how to read unknown XML using `local-name()` and `PIVOT` or *grouped aggregation* with dynamically created statements...

Answer (score 0):

### Writing the XML

To get your XML the way you describe it is simple:

```
SELECT * FROM AnySource FOR XML RAW(N'LabelData'),ELEMENTS,ROOT(N'NewDataSet')
```

This works for any table, view or table valued function...

### Reading the XML

Reading an unknown XML is easy, if your target is an *entity-key-value* tupel:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<NewDataSet>
    <LabelData>
        <Name>mol</Name>
        <Column>mol</Column>
        <Type>MOLIMAGE</Type>
        <!--More elements-->
        <TEST1>Only existing in 1</TEST1>
    </LabelData>
    <LabelData>
        <Name>2nd name</Name>
        <Column>2nd col</Column>
        <Type>2nd type</Type>
        <!--More elements-->
        <TEST2>Only existing in 2</TEST2>
    </LabelData>
</NewDataSet>';

WITH NewDataSet aS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS OrdPosition
          ,ld.query('./*') AS LabelDataElements
    FROM @xml.nodes(N'/NewDataSet/LabelData') AS A(ld)
)
SELECT ds.OrdPosition
      ,AllNodes.value(N'local-name(.)',N'nvarchar(max)') AS ElementName
      ,AllNodes.value(N'(./text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS ElementValue
FROM NewDataSet AS ds
CROSS APPLY ds.LabelDataElements.nodes(N'*') AS A(AllNodes);
```

results in

```
+-------------+-------------+--------------------+
| OrdPosition | ElementName | ElementValue       |
+-------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 1           | Name        | mol                |
+-------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 1           | Column      | mol                |
+-------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 1           | Type        | MOLIMAGE           |
+-------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 1           | TEST1       | Only existing in 1 |
+-------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2           | Name        | 2nd name           |
+-------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2           | Column      | 2nd col            |
+-------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2           | Type        | 2nd type           |
+-------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2           | TEST2       | Only existing in 2 |
+-------------+-------------+--------------------+
```

But writing this into a table with the `local-name()` as column header is more tricky. There are two scenarios:

- You knwo all possible column names in advance, even if not each and any XML must contain all of them.
- Your XMLs contain various and differing elements and you do not know there names in advance.

#### known column names

One big advantage: You - probably - know the data types and you can read/cast all values appropriately!

The column naming can be done with `PIVOT` or *grouped aggregate*, there are tons of examples to find...

Use `SELECT ... INTO SomeStagingTable FROM ...` to create a table on the fly.

#### Unknown column names

In this case I'd stick with the list of *entity-key-value* tupels. You might use dynamically created SQL for a dynamically defined `PIVOT` approach (many examples around!), but this is very difficult to use in later queries. There's not much sense in physical tables, where you do not know the structure...